Why my Worker Thread is not Printing Console log and Logger?
I am calling an worker Thread in My Node js application whose work is to take data from Redis Queue and process it(processing here include adding data to redis and also mongodb).
My useCase Here in processing Data includes:

Inserting Message to MongoDb.
Getting Data from Redis for Round Robin Agent Assignemnt.

Here my messages are the socket.io event which i push to redis queue and then process it one by one.
I am using typescript for this and i am making an worker.ts file whose work is to continuously listen to the redis queue and if the redis is not empty and then pop one message and process it.
This is called from my main app.ts file
 let worker = new Worker(path.join(__dirname, '../worker/messageprocessing.ts'));
console.log('worker thread started', worker);
worker.postMessage('message');
worker.on('done', (message) => {
  console.log('Worker Done', message);
  worker.postMessage('message');
});

This this is my messageProcessing ts file
async function processMessages(obj: any) {
  console.log('Processing messages from Redis queue... Thread', obj);
  try {
    await redisClient.connect();
    let obj: any = await redisClient.rPop(`queue`);
    if (obj != null) {
     //processing my logic.....
    }
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error('Worker message processing error', error);
  } finally {
    // Notify main thread that work is done
    parentPort && parentPort.postMessage('done');
  }
}

console.log('Listen to for called');

parentPort?.on('message', async (message) => {
  console.log('parent port called');
  await processMessages(message);
});

With this code when i am running this i cannot see any console log or any logger here can you help what i am doing wrong.
